# Brackets are wrong in this mathematical formula

Tags: brackets

[image]

This piece of code generates errors when compiling.
since this formula is long, it makes it hard for me to guess where are these errors. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\gamma_{c}=
\left\vert\frac{\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y1}E_{y2}^{*} \dA}
{\sqrt{(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y1}E_{y1}^{*} \dA)
(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y2}E_{y2}^{*} \dA)}}
\right\vert^2
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By making `\dA` unactive, i.e. `dA`, your equation works for me.

Comment: First, you should provide a full MWE, beginning with `\documentclass`.  Second, you should indicate what is "wrong".  You say "brackets are wrong", but `\vert` which produces the vertical line is not a bracket.

Comment: Andrea, thanks , you are right, the error is fixed by removing the symbol \ before dA. Steven, by brackets , I did not mean \vert, I meant the other brackets because I was always thinking the problem was with the brackets being not properly defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't defined the macro `\dA`. You may want to define it, say via a statement such as

```
\newcommand{\dA}{\,\mathrm{d}A}
```

More generally, though, you may want to define a macro for the "differential operator" `d` (frequently written in an upright font), say,

```
\newcommand\dee{\,\mathrm{d}}
```

and then write `\dee A` instead of `\dA`. (`\newcommand{\dee}{\mathop{}\!d}` works too, if you don't want an upright `d`...) The advantage of defining `\dee` rather than `\dA` is that it frees you from having to define lots of separate macros, say, `\dA`, `\dB`, `\dC`, etc. Of course, if you have lots and lots of instances of `\dee A`, you can still define `\newcommand{\dA}{\dee A}`.

Note also -- thanks, @egreg! -- that the subscripts `y1` and `y2` will not be typeset at the same depth unless you provide an "empty" superscript term -- `^{}` -- for the first of the two `E` expressions.

Separately, you may also want to place both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction in display style rather than text style. The resulting look is shown in the second displayed equation below. Note the use of `\biggl` and `\biggr` to size the parentheses in the denominator and of the `\!\!` (double negative thin space) directives to fine-tune the space between the double integral symbols and the integrands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\iint" macro
\newcommand{\dee}{\mathop{}\!d}  % "differential" operator
\newcommand{\dA}{\dee A}
\newcommand{\ddfrac}[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}

\begin{document}
%% version 1: numerator and denominator in text style, note the small integral symbols
\[
\gamma_{c}= \left\vert
\frac{\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y1}^{} E_{y2}^{*} \dA}
{\sqrt{\bigl(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y1}^{} E_{y1}^{*} \dA\bigr)
\bigl(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty E_{y2}^{} E_{y2}^{*} \dA \bigr)}}
\right\vert^2
\]

%% version 2: numerator and denominator in display style -- note the large integral symbols
\[
\gamma_{c}= \left\vert
\ddfrac{\iint_{-\infty}^\infty\!\! E_{y1}^{} E_{y2}^{*} \dA}
{\sqrt{\biggl(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty\!\! E_{y1}^{} E_{y1}^{*} \dA \biggr)
\biggl(\iint_{-\infty}^\infty\!\! E_{y2}^{} E_{y2}^{*} \dA\biggr)}}
\right\vert^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why defining `\dA` and not suggesting a (correct) macro for the differential symbol? You're also missing empty superscripts in `E_{y1}`; by using `E_{y1}^{}` you ensure the subscript is level with the one in `E_{y2}^{*}`.

Comment: @egreg - Good catch on the uneven placements of the subscripts -- I'll fix this. On defining `\dA` as a separate macro vs. defining something like `\dee` and writing `\dee A`: I chose the former option because the OP seemed to want it as a separate macro...

Comment: `\newcommand{\dee}{\mathop{}\!d}` and `\newcommand\dA{\dee A}`, of course. If you really want an upright “d” (which you shouldn't `;-)`), the change is just in one place and will affect all `\dee` (explicit or implicit).

Comment: egreg and Mico, I am still not sure what was the error with the subscripts exactly, I wish someone can re post the equation so that I compare and see what you mean. I also did not know how to lable this equation since there is no \begin{equation} or \end{equation} , I want to number the equation and be able to label it, any advice?

Comment: @Naema - To get a numbered equation that can be cross-referenced via `\label` and `\ref`, use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` instead of `\[` and `\]`. About the subscript: It's not (strictly speaking) an outright error to set them at different depths, but the equation does look neater (more competent?) if the subscripts are set at the same depth below the baseline. Try removing the `^{}` terms to obtain the not-so-neat look...